# Quicksort not sorting according to dates

Tags: python, date, quicksort

I wrote a Quicksort Algorithm but it doesn't sort the .txt file like i want to. It should sort them according to dates (in the form `day.month.year`). Instead `quicksort()` is sorting the file according to the day and don't consider the month and year.
Example:

```
05.01.2018 rr
03.01.2018 aa
01.04.2018 aba
02.02.2018 zystz
```

should be sorted to:

```
03.01.2018 aa
05.01.2018 rr
02.02.2018 zystz
01.04.2018 aba
```

but my code is sorting them like this:

```
01.04.2018 aba
02.02.2018 zystz
03.01.2018 aa
05.01.2018 rr
```

This is my `quicksort()` algorithm:

```
f = open(testfile)
arr = f.readlines()

def QuickSort(arr, start= 0, end=len(arr)-1):
    
    def partition(arr, starting, end):
        piv_index = starting
        piv = arr[piv_index]
    
        while starting < end:
            while starting < len(arr) and arr[starting] <= piv:
                starting += 1
            
            while arr[end] > piv:
                end -= 1
            
            if starting < end:
                arr[starting], arr[end] = arr[end], arr[starting]
            
        arr[end], arr[piv_index] = arr[piv_index], arr[end]
        
        return end

    if start < end:
        
        p = partition(arr, start, end)
        
        QuickSort(arr, start, p-1)
        QuickSort(arr, p+1, end)
    return(arr)

for s in QuickSort(arr):
    print(s)
```

Any suggestions?

Edit: I need to use `quicksort()` for an assignment so built-in sort functions like `sorted()` can't be used. The format should also stay day.month.year . Sorry that i didn't make it clear enough.

Comment: Why are you using a custom sort function instead of the built-in `sorted`? You already asked this once and got an answer which seems to cover this case too; your function doesn't seem to be doing anything to change the sort key from purely alphabetic.

Comment: If you change it to year month date then they will be sorted correctly.

Comment: Sorry, i should mention that we shouldn't use any built-in function like sorted(). Also the format need to stay day.month.year .